# Versioning a SharePoint feature

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a best practice for versioning SharePoint features?

Our SharePoint product gets a release every 3-6 months, and we need a way of clearly differentiating between the new version and the old version.  We also need to support simultaneous installations of the new and old feature so that clients may test the new stuff before deploying it.

Answer (score 4):

Versioning Features is not supported in Sharepoint 2007. In Sharepoint 2010 you can Version Features like you normally would version assemblies.

See the following post for more details: [Feature Versioning and Upgrades in SharePoint 2010](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/04/feature-versioning-and-upgrades-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a excellent webcast by Jeremy Thake on feature versiong and upgrade :

http://sharepointdevwiki.com/display/SPPodCasts/2010/06/22/SPWebCast+019+-+Deep+dive+into+feature+versioning+and+upgrade+support+in+SharePoint+2010

Answer (score 2):

Check out chapters 8 and 9 of our [free SharePoint development guidelines](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/05/muhimbis-sharepoint-development.html). We have been using this strategy successfully for the last few years in both SP2007 and SP2010.